# Filtrar um select2 ao selecionar uma oção em outro

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Eu tenho um campo do tipo select2 que está me trazendo todos os clientes de um banco de dados. Como eu faço para, ao selecionar um cliente, em outro select2 aparecer os contratos apenas do cliente selecionado, não consigo pensar em uma solução para isso, não tenho muito conhecimento sobre Ajax.
**EDITADO**

```
  $('#cliente').on('select2:selecting', function (e) {
$.get("orcamentocliente/"+$('#cliente').val(), function(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('#orcamentos').append($('<option>', {value:data[i].id, text:data[i].descricao+'-'+data[i].dataorcamento})).trigger('change');
  }
})
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "Erro ao carregar os orçamentos" );
  })
```

Eu criei essa rota 'orcamentocliente/' e passo o ID do cliente. Para uma função na controller que eu criei, porém, quando eu clico no cliente aparece o dele certinho, mas quando eu clico em outro cliente aparece o de todos. Abaixo o codigo do select do cliente:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                        {{ Form::label('cliente', 'Cliente') }}
                        <select class="js-example-basic-single" data-style="form-control" name="cliente_id" id="cliente" required="required">
                          <option> Selecione o cliente</option>
                          @forelse ($clientes as $cliente)
                          <option value="{{ $cliente->id }}">{{ $cliente->razaosocial }}</option>
                          @empty
                          <option value="">Nenhum item cadastrado</option>
                          @endforelse
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Comment: O ideal é AJAX mesmo, você já tem alguma coisa pronta?

Comment: Estou tentando trazer todos registros e filtrar usando o Select2 usando uma função JQuery.

Comment: Coloca o que puder de código para facilitar na montagem de um exemplo

Comment: Bom por enquanto ele esta assim:
  $('#cliente').on('select2:selecting', function (e) {
    //Ajax
    $.get( "orcamentocliente/"+$('#cliente').val(), function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#orcamentos').append($('<option>', {value:data[i].id, text:data[i].descricao+'-'+data[i].dataorcamento})).trigger('change');
      }
    })
      .fail(function() {
        alert( "Erro ao carregar os orçamentos" );
      })
  });

Comment: Para facilitar a leitura, adicione o código editando a pergunta.

Comment: Pronto kkk, editado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS

```
<script>
    $('#cliente').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route('sua_rota') }}',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
               _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
               cliente_id: $('#cliente').val(),
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data){
                if (data.success) {
                    $.each(data.options, function (i, item) {
                        $('#seuSelect').append($('<option>', { 
                            value: item.value,
                            text : item.text 
                        }));
                    });
                } else {
                    // Aqui trata se algo deu errado no servidor
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                // Aqui trata se algo deu errado na requisição AJAX
            }
         });
    });
</script>
```

ROTA

```
Route::post('sua_rota', 'SeuController@SeuMetodo')->name('sua_rota');
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function SeuMetodo(Request $request)
{
    $variavel = SeuModelo::find($request->cliente_id);

    // Sua lógica

    $options = //<-- AQUI VAI ARRAY DAS OPÇÕES DO SELECT [['value'=> $valor, 'text' => $text],['value'=> $valor, 'text' => $text]]

    if ($logica) { // <-- Se tudo deu certo na busca dos options
        return json_encode([ 'success' => true, 'options' => $options ]);
    } else { <-- Se alguma coisa deu errado na busca dos options
        return json_encode([ 'success' => false, 'options' => false ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nossa! Deu super certo, muito obrigado.